# Как настроить область видимости директивы ng-click в списке выводимых значений

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Есть таблица выводимых значений. При добавлении в нее дополнительного столбца с директивой ng-click функция testFunc не срабатывает, как я понимаю это связано с областью видимости. Если вместо директивы ng-click написать onclick (js функция), то все срабатывает.

В DOM - отображается все корректно.

```
<td ng-repeat="r in c.lients.rows" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
   <span ng-click="c.testFunc()">test</span>
</td>
```

Ниже представлены фрагменты кода.

HTML:

```html
<div ng-controller="IndexController as c">
  <table>
  <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="h in c.clients.header">{{h}}</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td ng-repeat="r in clients.rows">{{r}}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var vm = this;

  vm.clients = {
    "header": [
      "header 1",
      "header 2",
      "header 3"
    ],
    "rows": [
      "data 1",
      "data 2",
      "data 3"
    ]
  };

  vm.testFunc = function(){
    alert('test');
  }

  vm.header = "Телефоны";
  vm.telTest = '<span ng-click="c.testFunc()">test</span>';

  vm.clients.header.push(vm.header);
  vm.clients.rows.push(vm.telTest);
```

Как настроить область видимости директивы ng-click в списке выводимых значений?

Comment: То есть Вы вручную модифицируете DOM? Не надо этого делать, ангуляр это не любит. Ну или попробуйте вызвать `$compile` для содержимого td (но не уверен, насколько это поможет)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом

```js
vm.telTest = '<span onclick="angular.element(this).scope().c.testFunc()">test</span>';
```

Решение нашел здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html